# How do I find the right optimisation algorithm for my problem?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

*Disclaimer: I'm not a professional programmer or mathematician and this is my first time encountering the field of optimisation problems. Now that's out of the way so let's get to the problem at hand:*

I got several lists, each containing various items and number called 'mandatoryAmount':

```
listA (mandatoryAmountA, itemA1, itemA2, itemA2, ...)
```

Each item has certain values (each value is a number >= 0):

```
itemA1 (M, E, P, C, Al, Ac, D, Ab,S)
```

I have to choose a certain number of items from each list determined by 'mandatoryAmount'.
Within each list I can choose every item multiple times.

Once I have all of the items from each list, I'll add up the values of each.
For example:

```
totalM = listA (itemA1 (M) + itemA1 (M) + itemA3 (M)) + listB (itemB1 (M) + itemB2 (M))
```

The goals are:
-To have certain values (totalAl, totalAc, totalAb, totalS) reach a certain number cap while going over that cap as little as possible. Anything over that cap is wasted.
-To maximize the remaining values with different weightings each

The output should be the best possible selection of items to meet the goals stated above. I imagine the evaluation function to just add up all non-waste values times their respective weightings while subtracting all wasted stats times their respective weightings.

edit:
The total amount of items across all lists should be somewhere between 500 and 1000, the number of lists is around 10 and the mandatoryAmount for each list is between 0  and 14.

Comment: More a framework than an algorithm: integer programming. You can define integer variables, set linear inequalities, and maximize a linear objective. I'm partial to OR-Tools, but you have several competing options.

Comment: This looks like a more complex variant of knapsack problem, but I could be way off. You'll need to have goals very specific (eg, how do you evaluate solutions being better than another similar solution? Is it just about minimizing sum of wastage? How is minimizing and maximizing together supposed to be evaluated?) Have you got examples? Can the problem be simplified, solved in that form, and expanded back? How have you tried solving it yourself?

Comment: Roughly how many items are there total and roughly how big is the mandatory amount vs how big it could be? This is problem that becomes extremely hard to obtain the best possible solution as those two numbers go up.

Comment: @Nuclearman The total amount of items would be somewhere between 500 and 1000 and the mandatory amount of each list is between 0 and 14 with about 10 lists in total.

Comment: @domen The goals are to minimize waste and maximize all other stats. The evaluation would be done by summing up all non-waste stats and subtracting all wasted stats with each stat being weighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some sample code that uses Python 3 and OR-Tools. Let's start by
defining the input representation and a random instance.

```
import collections
import random

Item = collections.namedtuple("Item", ["M", "E", "P", "C", "Al", "Ac", "D", "Ab", "S"])
List = collections.namedtuple("List", ["mandatoryAmount", "items"])


def RandomItem():
    return Item(
        random.random(),
        random.random(),
        random.random(),
        random.random(),
        random.random(),
        random.random(),
        random.random(),
        random.random(),
        random.random(),
    )


lists = [
    List(
        random.randrange(5, 10), [RandomItem() for j in range(random.randrange(5, 10))]
    )
    for i in range(random.randrange(5, 10))
]
```

Time to formulate the optimization as a mixed-integer program. Let's import
the solver library and initialize the solver object.

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver("solver", "SCIP")
```

Make constraints for the totals that must reach a certain cap.

```
AlCap = random.random()
totalAl = solver.Constraint(AlCap, solver.infinity())
AcCap = random.random()
totalAc = solver.Constraint(AcCap, solver.infinity())
AbCap = random.random()
totalAb = solver.Constraint(AbCap, solver.infinity())
SCap = random.random()
totalS = solver.Constraint(SCap, solver.infinity())
```

We want to maximize the other values subject to some weighting.

```
MWeight = random.random()
EWeight = random.random()
PWeight = random.random()
CWeight = random.random()
DWeight = random.random()
solver.Objective().SetMaximization()
```

Create variables and fill in the constraints. For each list there is an
equality constraint on the number of items.

```
associations = []
for list_ in lists:
    amount = solver.Constraint(list_.mandatoryAmount, list_.mandatoryAmount)
    for item in list_.items:
        x = solver.IntVar(0, solver.infinity(), "")
        amount.SetCoefficient(x, 1)
        totalAl.SetCoefficient(x, item.Al)
        totalAc.SetCoefficient(x, item.Ac)
        totalAb.SetCoefficient(x, item.Ab)
        totalS.SetCoefficient(x, item.S)
        solver.Objective().SetCoefficient(
            x,
            MWeight * item.M
            + EWeight * item.E
            + PWeight * item.P
            + CWeight * item.C
            + DWeight * item.D,
        )
        associations.append((item, x))
if solver.Solve() != solver.OPTIMAL:
    raise RuntimeError
solution = []
for item, x in associations:
    solution += [item] * round(x.solution_value())
print(solution)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've been working with this the whole day and I'm still struggling with trying to understand what's exactly happening but it's been a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

I think David Eisenstat has the right idea with Integer programming, but let's see if we get some good solutions otherwise and perhaps provide some initial optimization. However, I think that we can just choose all of one item in each list may make this easier to solve that it normally would be. Basically that turns it into more of a Subset Sum problem. Especially with the cap.

There are two possibilities here:

1. There is no solution, no condition satisfies the requirement.
2. There is a solution that we need to be optimized.

We really want to try to find a solution first, if we can find one (regardless of the amount of waste), then that's nice.

So let's reframe the problem: We aim to simply minimize waste, but we also need to meet a min requirement. So let's try to get as much waste as possible in ways we need it.

I'm going to  propose an algorithm you could use that should work "fairly well" and is polynomial time, though could probably have some optimizations. I'll be using `K` to mean `mandatoryAmount` as it's a bit of a customary variable in this situation.  Also I'll be using `N` to mean the number of lists. Lastly, `Z` to represent the total number of items (across all lists).

1. Get the list of all items and sort them by the amount of each value they have (first the goal values, then the bonus values). If an item has `100A, 300C, 200B, 400D, 150E` and the required are `[B, D]`, then the sort order would look like: `[400,200,300,150,100]`. Repeat but for one goal value. Using the same example above we would have: `[400,300,150,100]` for `goal: D` and `[200,300,150,100]` for goal `B`. Create a boolean variable for optimization mode (we start by seeking for a solution, once we find one, we can try to optimize it). Create a counter/hash to contain the unassigned items. An item cannot be unassigned more than K times (to avoid infinite loops). This isn't strictly needed, but could work as an optimization for step 5, as it prioritize goals you actually need.
2. For each list, keep a counter of the number of assignable slots for each list, set each to `K`, as well as the number of total assignable slots, and set to `K * N`. This will be adjusted as needed along the way. You want to be able to quickly `O(1)` lookup for: a) which list an (sorted) item belongs to, b) how many available slots that item has, and c) How many times has the item been unassigned, d) Find the item is the sorted list.
3. General Assignment. While there are slots available (total slots), go through the list from highest to lowest order. If the list for that item is available, assign as many slots as possible to that item. Update the assignable and total slots. If result is a valid solution, record it, trip the "optimization mode flag". If slots remain unassigned, revert the previous unassignment (but do not change the assignment count).
4. Waste Optimization. Find the most wasteful item that can be unassigned (unassigned count < K). Unassign one slot of it. If in optimization mode, do not allow any of the goal values to go below their cap (skip if it would). Update the unassigned count for item. Goto #3, but start just after the wasteful item. If no assignment made, reassign this item until the list has no remaining assignments, but do not update the unassigned count (otherwise we might end up in an invalid state).
5. Goal value Optimization. Skip if current state is a valid solution. Find the value furthest from it's goal (IE: A/B/C/D/E above) that can be unassigned. Unassign one slot for that item. Update assignment count. Goto step 3, begin search at start of list (unlike Step 4), stop searching the list if you go below the value of this item (not this item itself, as others may have the same value). If no assignment made, reassign this item until the list has no remaining assignments, but do not update the unassigned count (otherwise we might end up in an invalid state).
6. No Assignments remain. Return current state as "best solution found".

Algorithm should end with the "best" solution that this approach can come up with. Increasing max unassignment counts may improve the solution, decreasing max assignment counts will speed up the algorithm. Algorithm will run until it has maxed out it's assignment counts.

This is a bit of a greedy algorithm, so I'm not sure it's optimal (in that it will always yield the best result) but it may give you some ideas as to how to approach it. It also feels like it should yield fairly good results, as it basically trying to bound the results. Algorithm performance is something like O(Z^2 * K), where K is the `mandatoryAmount` and `Z` is the total number of items. Each item is unassigned `K` items, and potentially each assignment also requires O(`Z`) checks before it is reassigned.

As an optimization, use a `O(log N)` or better delete/next operation sorted data structure to store the sorted lists. Doing so it would make it practical to delete items from the assignment lists once the unassignment count reaches `K` (rendering them no longer assignable) allowing for `O(Z * log(Z) * K)` performance instead.

Edit:
Hmmm, the above only works within a single list (IE: Item removed can only be added to it's own list, as only that list has room). To avoid this, do step 4 (remove too heavy) then step 5 (remove too light) and then goto step 3 (using step 5's rules for searching, but also disallow adding back the too heavy ones).

So basically we remove the heaviest one then the lightest one then we try to assign something that is as heavy as possible to make up for the lightest one we removed.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding this correctly but wouldn't this method try to reach the caps within each list separately? If that's the case, I'd end up with may more than the caps in total when all the lists are combined.

Comment: Initially yes. The first goal is very simple: Is there a solution at all? Is it even possible to reach the caps? This is done by the first run of #3. See the edit for a revision that avoids some issues. Next step is to remove the item that is exceeding it's cap the most and the one that is below it's cap the most. Then assign those slots to the next best options starting form the most to least weight that can be assigned. (that hasn't be unassigned too many times, because assignment means: Perhaps not the best option). In any case, looks like David added an answer.